# MongoDB: Querying by ObjectId with Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

Using MongoDB with the Java driver, I have a collection **users** that I want to query based on their ObjectId (the big picture: I am extrapolating from ObjectId to the object's creation timestamp).

The problem is, querying by **ObjectId** does not seem to work: I always get no results. 
For testing purposes, I have hardcoded in the search query the ObjectId of an existing user from the database, just to be sure that I should get results:

> { 
>      "_id": ObjectId("565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"),  ... }

Still, I never get any results.

These are the ways I have tried to build the query, together with the printout of the created query:

1.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b");
```

Query: **{ "_id" : "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"}**

2.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", new ObjectId("565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"));
```

Query: **{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"}}**

3.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b");
```

Query: **{ "_id" : "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"}**

4.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"));
```

Query: **{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"}}**

5.

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", 
        BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", new ObjectId("565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b")).get());
```

Query: **{ "_id" : { "$gte" : { "$oid" : "565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"}}}**

My application is deployed on OpenShift and I manually tried the queries in the RockMongo GUI; I get the same empty result.
However, if I manually search for **{ "_id" : ObjectId("565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b")}**, I get the correct result.

My question is: how can I correctly build the query so that it works?

Or, how can I get the Java Driver to produce an **ObjectId("...")** instead of an **{"$oid": "..."}** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code snippet below shows how you can query a Mongo collection by `_id`. Please note that `{ "$oid": "<id>" }` is the strict equivalent of `ObjectId( "<id>" )`. Strict mode representations of BSON types conform to the JSON RFC and allows any JSON parser to process these strict mode representations as key/value pairs.

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public DBObject findDocumentById(String id) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", new ObjectId(id));
    DBObject dbObj = collection.findOne(query);
    return dbObj;
 }
```

Comment: That's what I did in test #2, as described in my post. The query returns no result.

Comment: That suggest something else is wrong. Does a `findOne` query without a filter return any results ?

Comment: No, I get no results when invoking findOne(). However, queries on the users collection that use fields other than ObjectId and are invoked like collection.find(query) return the correct result.

Comment: What query is actually run by Mongo ? Can you start a mongod process with extended logging ?

Comment: Solved it -- when I saw the problems with find() vs findOne(), I double checked the code and indeed one of them was working on the wrong collection name ("user" vs "users"). So, PEBKAC again :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this style from @ImbaBalboa [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36729892/4505142)

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId("565ef85ee4b0a4db3c2fc96b"))).first();
```