# MongoDB java driver : filter by the id

Tags: java, mongodb

I use the latest version of the Java Driver of MongoDB. Unfortunately after searching I am not able to filter by an _id ...

I tried a lot of things :

```
_id id_objet = new _id();
id_objet.set$oid(idobjet);

Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", id_objet)).first();
```

I got a bad request error with Grizzly ...

What is the proper way to filter by _id with the latest version of the driver ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was finally not a big deal :

```
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("_id", new ObjectId(idobjet))).first();
```

You have to use ObjectId(id).